# On the definition of totally unimodular matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-optimization, unimodular-matrices, total-unimodularity

I'm a bit confused about the definition of a totally unimodular matrix, since my lecture notes states that this matrix is not totally unimodular:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 0 \\ 1 && -1 \\ -2 && 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't see a submatrix which doesn't have a determinant in $\lbrace 0,\pm1 \rbrace$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Schrijver's [Theory of Linear and Integer Programming](https://www.wiley.com/en-ie/Theory+of+Linear+and+Integer+Programming-p-9780471982326) (1998):

> In Chapters 19 to 21 we consider *totally unimodular matrices*, which are matrices with all subdeterminants equal to $1$, $-1$, or $0$ (in particular, each entry is $1$, $-1$, or $0$). Totally unimodular matrices yield a prime class of linear programming problems with integral optimum solutions.

---

Note that $-2 \notin \{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah, the wiki page didn't seem to mention this. Maybe I overlooked smt, or we're just dealing with different definitions. Thanks anyway, I guess your answer is correct, since Schrijver's book indeed is pensum for this class. Thanks!